# Typescript - check null value in an other method

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm on a Typescript project with "strict" set to true in tsconfig.js.
I got some problem with the following code

```
export class MyClass {
  
  private _val: number | null;

  constructor(val: number | null) {
    this._val = val;
  }

  public isValid(): boolean {
      return this._val != null;
  }

  public test1(): number {
    return this._val; 
  }

  public test2(): number {
    if(this._val != null) 
    return this._val;
    return 0; 
  }

  public test2(): number {
    if(this.isValid()) 
    return this._val;
    return 0; 
  }
}
```

At the moment, methods test1() and test3() reports an error, while test2() compile fine.
I would like to know if there is a way to configure tsconfig in order to have

- test1() reports an error because we not check the returned value
- test2() compiles fine because we check the returned value
- test3() compiles fine. As in test2() we check that this._val is not null, but in an other method

Brett

Comment: Not possible even with assertions and type predicates since `_val` is *private*.

Comment: Does not matter if its public or private, the results seems the same

Comment: It certainly matters if it's public, since if it is, you can define a type predicate method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx3GxN).  If that meets your needs I (or maybe @caTS) can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply in a comment and want me to be notified, please mention @jcalz)

Comment: Nope, if you make it public, then you can use a type predicate: https://tsplay.dev/N5LDVw (the exact same as jcalz's; didn't see before I posted this).

Comment: @jcaz thank you for the suggestion. I learned something today. However, I want the value to be private, therefore I can't use your solution. Because I know the value can't be null thanks to isValid() method, I think I will go with a '@ts-ignore'